# What could it be: つもりでいた？?

Tags: grammar, usage

I need some help with the sentence below. Things like ～ている、～でいる when finishing the verb as in [似]{に}**ている**、[読]{よ}ん**でいる** are okay for me. But next sentence is something else, because the ending でいた is standing after a noun, not a verb.

> 結婚した後、日本語を勉強するつもり**でいた**が、生活のために始めた仕事は、フランス語を教えること。

- Could you please explain, why でいた was used here, in this sentence?
- And when we can usually use grammar like this?

Comment: It's just a basic te-form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a valid combination of two things you already know:

- te-form + いた  forms the past-progressive
- the te-form of the copula is で

so we have:

- 日本語を勉強するつもりだ -> intend to study Japanese
- 日本語を勉強するつもり**でいた** -> **was
  intending** to study Japanese